# Elaticsearch Field property missing for Date

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I used to have an old Elasticsearch 6.8 index where I had a subfield `.sortable` for some properties in the mapping. Some were `Keywords` and others `Date`.

I used that naming convention, so that I could automatically use `<myProperty>.sortable` in my custom queryBuilder when the user asked for a specific ordering.

Since I upgraded my Elasticsearch to version 8, all my `Date` properties lost their `.sortable` subfields, but not the `Keyword` ones.

The documentation does not mention de `fields` parameter for `Date` in [version 8](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.11/date.html) , but it wasn't there in [version 6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/date.html) either. However, it is mentionned for `Keyword` in both versions (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html)

Is it possible to still have a subfield on `Date` properties in Elasticsearch 8?